# Fortran declarations using PETSc's key words not recognized in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, fortran, petsc

I'm using VSCode with Modern Fortran+fortls to write Fortran code with PETSc library. The declaration using PETSc's key words seems not being recognized at all. I tried to include the path of PETSc library and header files in .fortls file using include_dirs etc, but it does not resolve the issue. Can anyone give me a hint so the all the keywords and function declarations in PETSc can be handled by fortls? Thanks a lot

I used the following in the .fortls file

```
{
  "source_dirs": ["./**","./src/**",                                                                
    "/Users/apple/local/petsc/osx-gfc/include/**",                                                   
    "/Users/apple/local/petsc/include/**",                                                           
    "/Users/apple/local/petsc/include/petsc/finclude",                                               
    "/Users/apple/local/petsc/src/vec/f90-mod",                                                      
    "/Users/apple/local/petsc/src/ksp/f90-mod",                                                      
    "/Users/apple/local/petsc/src/vec/f90-mod",                                                      
    "/Users/apple/local/petsc/src/dm/f90-mod",                                                       
    "/Users/apple/local/petsc/src/mat/f90-mod"                                                       
  ],                                                                                                
  "include_dirs": ["./include/**",                                                                  
    "/Users/apple/local/petsc/osx-gfc/include/**",                                                   
    "/Users/apple/local/petsc/include/**",                                                           
    "/Users/apple/local/petsc/include/petsc/finclude/",                                              
    "/Users/apple/local/petsc/src/ksp/f90-mod",                                                      
    "/Users/apple/local/petsc/src/vec/f90-mod",                                                      
    "/Users/apple/local/petsc/src/snes/f90-mod"                                                      
  ],                                                                                                
  "ext_source_dirs": ["/Users/apple/local/petsc/src/snes/f90-mod/",                                  
    "/Users/apple/local/petsc/src/sys/f90-mod/",                                                     
    "/Users/apple/local/petsc/osx-gfc/include/**",                                                   
    "/Users/apple/local/petsc/src/vec/f90-mod",                                                      
    "/Users/apple/local/petsc/src/dm/f90-mod",                                                       
    "/Users/apple/local/petsc/src/mat/f90-mod",                                                      
    "/Users/apple/local/petsc/src/ksp/f90-mod",                                                      
    "/Users/apple/local/petsc/src/vec/f90-mod"                                                       
  ],                                                                                                
  "hover_language": "fortran90",                                                                    
  "hover_signature": true,                                                                          
  "use_signature_help": true  
}
```

But the type keyword like SNES and KSP are not recognized by the IDE at all.

Comment: What does "The declaration using PETSc's key words seems not being recognized at all." mean? You do not see the functiin signatures or what? Please try to come up with some title that somehow tells what kind actual of problem you have, not that you have some question about something. There are tags to tell us what your question is roughly about. The title should be more specific. Please check what I tried, but it probably needs refining (considering the first question in this comment).

Comment: Also, be sure to use the right tags so that the right experts see your question. The [tag:visual-studio-code] tag is really important.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Vladimir. The function signature for all PETSc routines is not seen, and VSCode complains not recognizing the snes variable passed to subroutines that I defined and declared. And the "use petsc" and "use petscsys" instructions got complaints of no modules found. Those are what I have seen from the vscode

Comment: Well, as PETSc's manual explains, I can use " type(tKSP) ksp" to define object ksp  for use, and same is true for SNES object. But those PetscErrorCode etc. can not be declared as derived type. I guess there is something missing in the preprocessing but I don't know what to add yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to slightly tweak your language server settings. You are attempting to use the PETSc preprocessor variables without "defining" them in the language server. Parsing files containing preprocessor macros can sometimes be a bit flimsy in the language server.

Assuming you are using [`fortls`](https://gnikit.github.io/fortls) you can define preprocessor definitions as shown in the documentation, see: https://gnikit.github.io/fortls/options.html#pp-defs

You should also be able to do that via the VS Code settings.

Beware of this bug (https://github.com/gnikit/fortls/issues/72) where defining a preprocessor macro will override actual fortran tokens like .`IF` or `ELSE`

---

Full disclosure I am the author of fortls and the Modern Fortran vscode extension

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great work in fortls! It seems this pp_defs works for Mat as in your example. So we need to provide those definition of preprocessor to all the key words like PetscMPIInt etc.? It will be a long list if we need to do it this way and I don't know if there is a limit for the number of items we can add to pp-defs

Comment: BTW, thanks a lot for your answer to my question!

Comment: No worries, glad you find fortls useful. Technically, fortls is capable of parsing source files and making these preprocessor definition assignments automatically. The problem is that sometimes this parsing fails so you have to manually parse the definitions. I think PETSc has an `finclude.h` file among many others that contain the core of the Fortran preproc definitions. Try and use the `pp_suffixes` and `include_dirs` to specify the location of these external includes, but don't overuse them since it will make it difficult to trace where a PP def is coming from.

Comment: Thanks. I will try pp_suffixes and include_dirs to see what I can get.